# How to fetch object via spring data(jpql) that is in relation via next other object

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using spring data with JPQL grouping select, everything works and stats are counted, but when I want to acces to competition object I'm getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I have these entities that I want to collect for stats

```
@Entity
public class BetCourse {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MATCH_ID", nullable = false)
    private BetMatch betMatch;
}

@Entity
public class BetMatch {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "betMatch")
    private List<BetCourse> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPETITION_ID", nullable = false)
    private Competition competition;
}

@Entity
public class Competition {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "competition")
    private List<BetMatch> betMatches = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "competition")
    private List<Stats> stats = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And I'm digging data from these classes to the Stats class

```
@Entity
public class Stats {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPETITION_ID", nullable = false)
    private Competition competition;
}
```

via this select:

```
@Query("select new Stats(" +
            "c.course, " +
            "c.courseType, " +
            "count(*), " +
            "SUM(CASE WHEN win = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), " +
            "c.betMatch.competition) " +
            "from BetCourse c " +
            group by c.course, c.betMatch.competition, c.courseType")
    public List<Stats> computeStatsByBetShop();
```

and when I acces to competiton object

```
stat.getCompetition()
```

How can I fetch this object? Is it possible to somehow combine with join fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating some code spike, I came with a solution that is pretty easy and straight to follow. Instead of starting your JPQL from the BetCourse table, and do the joins from there, you should start from the Competition table, and then do the inner joins until BetCourse.

This is because from the point of view of BetCourse, the entity is a ManyToOne, and them the JPA somehow get lost. Just doing in the inverse order solve your issue.

```
@Query("select new Stats(" +
        "c.course, " +
        "c.courseType, " +
        "count(c), " +
        "SUM(CASE WHEN win = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), " +
        "cpt) " +
        "from Competition cpt " +
        "inner join cpt.betMatches bm " +
        "inner join bm.courses c " +
        "group by c.course, c.courseType, cpt")
@ReadOnlyProperty
public List<Stats> computeStatsByBetShop();
```

And here goes a GitHub [minimum code](https://github.com/enikolas/jpa-group-by-lazy-issue) following your classes, so you can use it as example, in case it still does not work for you.

Cheers, Nikolas

Comment: I'm getting this when I use this code: Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=bm,role=com.patientandrich.model.database.BetCourse.betMatch,tableName=bet_match,tableAlias=betmatch1_,origin=bet_course betcourse0_,columns={betcourse0_.match_id ,className=com.patientandrich.model.database.BetMatch}}]

Comment: Oops, I think I have put one extra join fetch. Try to remove the last one, and just let the "join fetch c.betMatch bm". I have edited my answer. If it still does not work, I'll try to create here some minimum project with the same structure and see why it does not work. But could you try this small fix first?

Comment: I tried it and stil the same error :/ shouldn't be something different when I want to fetch many to one relation?

Comment: @user1604064 could you edit your question, and put a minimum executable entity for the ones involved in your question? I'm trying to create here an spike code to execute it myself, but there is some part missing on the one you have post. Then I can create an example code on github and provide it to you. Cheers

Comment: @user1604064 I just edited my answer and have provided to you a code (in github) that works and was properly tested by mySelf. I hope now it solves your issue. Cheers

Comment: Hi Nikolas, I'm sorry for delayed, but I want to say many thanks for you because it works like a charm!!